# Combo Box Binding list some times empty. how to handle this

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox which is bound to a CollectionView(AvailableSampleTypes). 
In some scenarios this list can have no items ("SampleTypeOptionVisibility" is collapsed in such scenarios), but still the combobox is trying to bind itself and throws an exception. 
How can I handle this?

```xml
<DockPanel Visibility="{Binding SampleTypeOptionVisibility}">
     <TextBox Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.QC_SampleType}"/>
     <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableSampleTypes}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" 
                SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedSampleType}" 
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsSampleTypeEnabled}" />
</DockPanel> 




public CollectionView AvailableSampleTypes
        {
            get { return new CollectionView(sampleTypeDefinitionsList); }
        }
public string SelectedSampleType
 {
    get
       {
        var solution = SelectedSolution as IExpandedQcTestSolution;
        if (solution != null)
        {
           return solution.SampleTypeId.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
           return sampleTypeDefinitionsList.ToList()[0].Id.ToString();
        }
   }
  set
   {
     var solution = SelectedSolution as IExpandedQcTestSolution;
     if (solution != null)
     {
        var sampleTypeDef = sampleTypeDefinitionsList.First(x => x.Id == new Guid(value));
        solution.SampleTypeId = sampleTypeDef.Id;

     }
   }  
}
```

the "sampleTypeDefinitionsList" has a list of "ExpandedQCSampleTypeDefinition"

```
public class ExpandedQCSampleTypeDefinition
        {            
            public Guid Id { get; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *"In some scenarios"* Could you include a [mcve]  to showcase one of those scenarios?

Comment: The DockPanel visibility is not connect if the ComboBox will bind the data or not

Comment: Catch the exception or get rid of it.